# Create file JSON online

Tags: android, json

I have worked with parsing JSON and I want to create a JSON file online. Have the website support to create file JSON online?

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice online JSON editor at http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/.

Please note that I had never heard of such tools before reading this question, because I usually never write JSON by hand except for a few special cases. JSON is meant before all as a language that can be easily generated and parsed by machines.

(The special case I mentionned are some configuration files, and using nicely formatted and commented JSON, because the compact notation is definitly not human-friendly.)

Comment: I create file JSON to use in my example.Thank Darius